# Sidebar Box to the left of questions on meta highly unreadable

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

There is not enough contrast here, I feel as though this change was recent as I have not noticed this before.

[image: Can you see that? I cannot, the contrast is off]

All the notes have white text on light backgrounds.

[image: How to ask box]

- Chrome 18.0.1025.163 Mac
- Safari 5.1.1 (6534.51.22)
- Firefox 3.6.23
- IPhone 3GS 5.1 Safar (Full site mode)
- Chromium 19.0.1076.0 *Basically I'm trying to say it's unreadable everywhere ;)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the fix will be in the next production build.